# Laravel 5.3 route Post not working

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

Hi i recently moved to Laravel 5.3 and i have this problem which works on 5.2

i have simple form and i want to redirect to index when user submit it:

```
 <form method="post" action="{{ route('create') }}">
         <div class="input-group">
            <label for="movie">Title Of Movie</label>
            <input type="text" name="movie" id="movie" placeholder="Title Of Movie">
         </div>
          <div class="input-group">
             <label for="author">Your Name</label>
             <input type="text" name="author" id="author" placeholder="Your Name">
          </div>
          <div class="input-group">
             <label for="email">Your Email</label>
             <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email">
          </div>
          <div class="input-group">
             <label for="quote">Your Quote</label>
             <textarea name="quote" rows="5" id="quote" placeholder="Your Quote"></textarea>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit Quote</button>
          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
       </form>
```

now this is my route/web.php:

```
Route::get('/',[
  'uses' => 'QuoteController@getIndex',
  'as'   => 'index'
]);

Route::post('/new',[
   'uses' => 'QuoteController@postQuote',
   'as' => 'create'

]);
```

and also this is my Quotecontroller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Author;
use App\Quote;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class QuoteController extends Controller
{
  public function getIndex(){
      return view('index');
  }

  public function postQuote(Request $request){

      $authorText = ucfirst($request['author']);
      $quoteText = $request['quote'] ;

      $author = Author::where('name', $authorText)->first();
      if(!$author){
        $author = new Author();
        $author->name = $authorText;
        $author->save();
      }
      $quote = new Quote();
      $quote->quote = $quoteText;
      $author->quotes()->save($quote);


     return redirect()->route('index')->with([
       'success' => 'Quote Saved!'
     ]);
  }

}
```

the error i get is when i submit:

NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

and i really don't understand the problem please Help

Comment: I am also learning laravel and I have never used the route() in forms before so you may try <form method="POST" action="/new">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    ...
</form> and remove the named route for the time being from the web routes file

Comment: hi i did all things you said but its not work again and also i don't think /new be correct way because you need to use route

Comment: actually if you check the docs you may use the action directly without route() inside the form tag so that is not an issue and just to check with you again I hope that you are not testing on live server and not uploading your file to the ftp ( silly check but sometimes we may miss it )

Comment: The error is generated with the first route `route('create')` or the second one `route('index')`, what is the URL displayed in your browser?

Comment: the error i get is :                                                                                                                         Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.                                        on /new URL

Answer (score 0):

when you are extending `Controller` you must use `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` and don't forget to use also `{{ csrf_field() }}` in your form.

Comment: hi i try thing s you said but i get error that the controller not exist

Comment: OK do you mean:                                                                                                        namespace App\Http\Controllers\Controllers; and also i'm sorry what is this {{csrf_field() }} is this new in 5.3 because i always used:                                                 <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">

Answer (score 0):

hey guys i found the problem and thats really funny 
before i tell you whats wrong i should tell you that i had this project on the folder that was for Git-hub so when i make changes i can add comment but the problem was actually that i named my folder **Test** and uppercase named folder was problem so when i change it to **test** it works
thank you for your answers